# Excel VBA w/ selenium wrapper: entering and inputting data into web form fields

Tags: vba, excel, selenium

Using a selenium wrapper, how can I input the data of my choosing into the input value placeholder below? This is for web scraping purposes. Site code below:

```
<input value="" placeholder="Enter Text" autocomplete="off" aria-
label="Enter Text: name and age required" data-
reactid=".9odxj7ein7k.0.0.9.0.0.$body.2.9.0.0.9.0.0.0.9.0">
```

Here's my current VBA code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim bot As New WebDriver
bot.Start "chrome", "url”

Set the_input_elements = bot.Document.getElementsByID("input value")
For Each input_element In the_input_elements
If input_element.getAttribute("input value") = "" Then
    input_element.Value = "Text I would like to enter to the form"
    Exit For
End If
Next input_element

End Sub
```

Comment: So a couple things, an ElementID is by definition unique, so the `getElementsByID` should be `getElementByID`. Also `input` is the tag name, an id is marked by a property `id="SomeID"`. I think what you want is to select all the input TagNames on the page, then find a property that is unique-ish. It looks like you can use the `label` or `reactid`.

Comment: @ryanwildry thanks for the insight. I made a few of your tweaks and I can get the updated code to work without a selenium wrapper (using IE). The only reason I am using the wrapper is because the webpage will not fully load when using IE -- so I have two paths: 
1) get the IE page to fully load (I have `Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4` but this page is heavy on content); 
or 2) get the selenium wrapper code to work (bug seems to be in `Set the_input_elements = bot.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")` note this code works perfectly for non-selenium wrapper solution).
Thank you.